# PHP - How can I make handwriting recognition japanese in website

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, handwriting, handwriting-recognition

Recently, I'm study about handwriting recognition Japanese project. I'm searching somewhere but still not received good info about this. Could someone give me some guess or tips about handwriting recognition on website by PHP and ajax.

Comment: You're looking for OCR software with a Japanese alphabet/dictionary.

Comment: Have a look at tesseract:https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php

Comment: I see this project and try tesseract, but with handwrite image. It's give me bad character. Could you give me some project like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a neural network. It is easy of implementing.
Also you could use a classifier, take into account you have lots of training data on internet then a supervised algorithm could be the best option.
Check this course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

Answer (score 0):

I am working at MyScript where we build one web component that could help you integrate Japanese handwriting recognition in your web application. As explain [here](https://github.com/MyScript/myscript-text-web), you only have to grab two dependencies and then add the myscript-text-web tag in your markup

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/myscript-text-web/myscript-text-web.html">
</head>
<body>
    <myscript-text-web 
        applicationkey="#PUT YOUR MYSCRIPT CDK APPLICATION KEY HERE#" 
        hmackey="#PUT YOUR MYSCRIPT CDK HMAC KEY HERE#" 
        language="ja_JP">
    </myscript-text-web>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to populate one input field with the recognition result you can add this piece of javascript :

```
var myScriptTextWeb = document.querySelector('myscript-text-web');
myScriptTextWeb.addEventListener('myscript-text-web-result',(evt) => {
    console.log(myScriptTextWeb.firstcandidate);
    // assuming the inpput you want to populate have id myinput
    document.querySelector('#myinput').value = myScriptTextWeb.firstcandidate;

})
```

Hope this helps